# How do you make an anchor link non-clickable or disabled?

Tags: html, jquery

I have an anchor link that I want to disable once the user clicks on it. Or, remove the anchor tag from around the text, but definitely keep the text.

```
<a href='' id='ThisLink'>some text</a>
```

I can do this easily with a button by adding `.attr("disabled", "disabled");`
I successfully added the disabled property, but the link was still clickable.
I don't really care if the text is underlined or not.

Any clue?

When you click on the wrong musician, it should just add "Wrong" and then become unclickable.
When you click and you are correct, it should add "Awesome" and then disable all `<a>` tags.

Comment: remove the href part and add to your CSS : "cursor:pointer", I assume you have a $('#ThisLink').click or something like that?

Comment: $("#ThisLink").parent().find("a").remove();

Comment: Adam, this solution almost works. It gets rid of all of the text within the a tag though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just realized what you were asking for(I hope). Here's an ugly solution

```
var preventClick = false;

$('#ThisLink').click(function(e) {
    $(this)
       .css('cursor', 'default')
       .css('text-decoration', 'none')

    if (!preventClick) {
        $(this).html($(this).html() + ' lalala');
    }

    preventClick = true;

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This could actually really solve the problem, sort of...

Instead of .click, use .on on the body and delegate to 'a[disabled]'.
Then put the css code in the actual css using the same selector.

Then, preventing click is as simple as event.preventDefault() and return false

Comment: Disagree, use CSS "pointer-events: none;" instead, just like in other unswers.

Answer (score 213):

The cleanest method would be to add a class with pointer-events:none when you want to disable a click. It would function like a normal label.

```
.disableClick{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Using this idea a even easier way would be to use a[disabled] as selector for the css so you would not require to add the .disableClick class to the anchor

Comment: Be careful though as you can still tab to things disabled with pointer-events: none

Comment: this solution is good for me in modern browsers. i have usable anchor tags that are bound to click events, and to discourage spamming them as their processes do their thing i programmatically add this and then remove it when the process is done. tabbing to a disabled anchor tag in my case isnt a concern either, but may be for others. YMMV

Comment: Using `pointer-events:none` will also disable `cursor`, title text, and other mouseover events.

Comment: _the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead._
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

That might be an issues on some layouts

Comment: True @user2988142. But the answer satisfies the requirements of the original poster. It would be bad design to have an anchor link on top of another clickable area. Would love to see functional design layouts with such issues.

Comment: Pairing this with `tabindex="-1"` appears to satisfy all the use cases except for a click event being generated in JavaScript.

Comment: Nice. I also added text-decoration: none to remove the underline.

Comment: This is wrong: it disables interacting with the text inside the anchor completely, not just clicking it.

Answer (score 40):

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>some text</a>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution so that future visitors to this question will understand how it solves the problem at hand.

Comment: From: [MDN: The void Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

When a browser follows a `javascript: URI`, it evaluates the code in the URI and then replaces the contents of the page with the returned value, unless the returned value is `undefined`. The `void` operator can be used to return `undefined`. For example:
    `<a href="javascript:void(0);">`
        `Click here to do nothing`
    `</a>`

Note, however, that the `javascript:` pseudo protocol is discouraged over other alternatives, such as unobtrusive event handlers.

Answer (score 37):

Use **pointer-events** CSS style. (as Jason MacDonald suggested)

See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events.
Its supported in most browsers.

Simple adding "disabled" attribute to anchor will do the job if you have global CSS rule like following:

```
a[disabled], a[disabled]:hover {
   pointer-events: none;
   color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding the styling through the [disabled] attribute rather than a class. It should be noted that pointer-events: none; doesn't work in anything older than IE11 though.

Comment: All IEs has its own proprietary logic of disabling anchor, buttons and even other elements by default.This workaround needed for non-IE browsers.

Comment: +1. Just so I don't have to look it up again next time: required javascript (using jQuery) would be `$("#elementid").attr("disabled", "disabled");`. Also may be helpful to include `cursor: default` in the CSS (as suggested by Muhammad Nasir).

Comment: A elements don't have a *disabled* attribute, using it as a selector may or may not work.

Comment: This solution also works well with non-javascript dynamic templates found in frameworks like Django. Ex: `<a href="#" {% if <INSERT CONDITION> %}disabled{% endif %}>`

Comment: Intuitive - good solution. I was actually surprised to find that `<a />` elements don't have a disabled attribute - seems odd.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('a').removeAttr('href')
```

or

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false})
```

It depends on situation

Comment: Removing the a via the removeAttr doesn't work for me.  .removeAttr("href")  http://www.awesomealbums.info/?WhoAmI

Answer (score 11):

Bootstrap provide us with `.disabled` class. Please use it.

But `.disabled` class only works when the 'a' tag already has class 'btn'. It doesn' t work on any old 'a' tag. The `btn` class may not be appropriate in some context as it has style connotations. Under the covers, the `.disabled` class sets `pointer-events` to `none`, so you can make CSS to do the same thing as Saroj Aryal and Vitrilo have sugested. (Thank you, Les Nightingill for this advice).

Comment: the .disabled class only works when the 'a' tag already has class 'btn'. It doesn' t work on any old 'a' tag. The 'btn' class may not be appropriate in some context as it has style connotations. Under the covers, the .disabled class sets pointer-events to none, so you can make css to do the same thing as Saroj Aryal and Vitrilo have sugested.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. It clarifies a lot for many users. May I use some text from your comment to extend my answer?

Answer (score 9):

Add a `css` class:

```
.disable_a_href{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Add this `jquery`:

```
$("#ThisLink").addClass("disable_a_href");
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to prevent the default action. In the case of anchor tag, the default behavior is redirecting to `href` specified address.

So following javascript works best in the situation:

```
$('#ThisLink').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Write this a single line of jQuery Code

```
$('.hyperlink').css('pointer-events','none');
```

if you want to write in css file

```
.hyperlink{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the onclick event to disable the click action:

```
<a href='' id='ThisLink' onclick='return false'>some text</a>
```

Or you could just use something other than an `<a>` tag.

Comment: You can combine this with `text-decoration: none` and `.disabledLink { color: #000 !important; }` to make it appear like regular text.

Comment: obtrusive javascript is a terrible solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `href` attribute from the anchor tag.

Comment: In some browsers removing href simply sets href to / or the current page.

Comment: I think this should be the first approach

Answer (score 4):

Jason MacDonald comments worked for me, tested in Chrome, Mozila and IE.

Added gray color to show disable effect.

```
.disable_a_href{
    pointer-events: none;
    **color:#c0c0c0 !important;**
}
```

Jquery was selecting only first element in the anchor list, added meta character (*) to select and disable all element with id `#ThisLink`.

```
$("#ThisLink*").addClass("disable_a_href");
```

Answer (score 3):

Create following  class in style sheet :

```
  .ThisLink{
           pointer-events: none;
           cursor: default;
    }
```

Add this class to you link  dynamically as follow.

```
 <a href='' id='elemID'>some text</a>

    //   or using jquery
<script>
    $('#elemID').addClass('ThisLink');
 </script>
```

Comment: How is this any different from Jason MacDonald's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20710360/369450)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I used to disable.Hope it helps.

```
$("#ThisLink").attr("href","javascript:;");
```

Comment: This is the simple and easy solution and should be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: what is the anchor holds styling rules that are essential to their program, this is a fix that disregards css

Answer (score 1):

Simply in SASS:

```
.some_class{
     // styles...

     &.active {
       pointer-events:none;
     }
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Never trust** the browser because the user can change the page in any way without the server's knowledge.

If a link is to work only once, the first thing you need to do is *make sure that server side the click is accepted only once* (with an onetime token specified as querystring for example), because the URL present in the href attribute can be copied by the user and inserted in the navigation bar of the browser and runned multiple times.

On the javascript side, the safest thing you can do is completely replace the `<a>` link with another tag, preserving the content:

```
/** Replace element, preserving attributes and moving descendant nodes from the previous one.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} element Element to be replaced changing tag.
 * @param {String} new_tag New element tag.
 * @return {HTMLElement} New created element.
 */
function rename_element_tag(element, new_tag) {
    let new_block = document.createElement(new_tag);
    for (let j = 0; j < element.attributes.length; ++j)
        new_block.setAttribute(element.attributes[j].name, element.attributes[j].value);

    $(new_block).insertAfter(element);
    while (element.childNodes.length > 0)
        new_block.appendChild(element.childNodes[0]);

    $(element).remove();

    return new_block;
}
```

This function replaces the passed element in place by "modifying" the tag, and preserves attributes and content by iterating all child nodes via vanilla javascript instead of jQuery to handle text nodes as well.

In your case you must skip the `href` attribute.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#ThisLink').one('click',function(){
  $(this).bind('click',function(){
    return false;
  });
});
```

This would be another way to do this, the handler with `return false`, which will disable the link, will be added after one click.

Answer (score -4):

The easyest way

In your html:

```
<a id="foo" disabled="true">xxxxx<a>
```

In your js:

```
$('#foo').attr("disabled", false);
```

If you use it as attribute works perfectly

Comment: disabled is not a valid attribute for the <a> tag