# Disable link on change jquery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is disable the link. How to disable link if dropdown select value was change?

If I select add in dropdown, edit and remove link should be disable. Help?

```
<select id="">
<option value="add" selected="selected">Add</option>
<option value="edit">Edit</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>

  <a class="button add" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Add Purchase Request</b></span></a>
  <a class="button edit" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>
  <a class="button remove" style="cursor:pointer;" name="remove"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a>
```

Comment: you can't disable an anchor element, do you have click handlers for these links

Comment: @ArunPJohny If can't disable, if it possible to void it?

Comment: Why not hide the anchors other than the one that matches the select?

Comment: you can either hide them... or add a class like disabled to them.. and on their click handler if it is disabled don't do anything

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links for a discussion of several additional options.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var va = $(this).val();
    if(va=='add'){
      $('.remove').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('.remove').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your anchors based on the selected option instead:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    $('a.button').eq(index).show().siblings('a').hide();
}).change();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r46Kq/2/)**

Comment: my other link also hide