# Disabled attribute in img tag in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

There is a difference between IE10 and other browsers with disabled attribute in  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Img Tag </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abc() {
            alert("Hi");
        }
    </script>
    <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" onload="abc()" onclick="abc()"  src="./testimg.png" disabled />
 </body>
</html>
```

IE10 is respecting disabled property and both onload & onclick not firing. If I remove disabled attribute, it is firing both the events.

But, Chrome is not not respecting the disabled property. I mean, it is firing both the events, irrespective of disabled attribute.

My question is,
 Can I use disabled property in  tag? 
 if yes, What is the correct behavior, IE10 or Chrome? is it a bug in cherome?

Comment: `disabled` only works on form elements.

Comment: Vucko please check this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/disabledisappliedto.htm

Comment: @Mohammed Imran Khan: That's for JavaScript properties, not HTML attributes.

Comment: `disabled` is not valid for `img` elements check the [HTML5 specs: The img element - Content attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-img-element). If vendors change the behavior of the `img` element when `disabled` is added, then they don't behave correctly. The closest thing  would probably be [aria-disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-disabled).

Answer (score 1):

No specification or public draft allows `disabled` for the `a` element. So Chrome is right and IE is wrong. Interestingly, documentation of [`a` element on IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#) does not mention the `disabled` attribute (only the `isDisabled` property).

Cf. [How to disable HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links).

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML 5 specification:

- img is not listed among the [elements that can be disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#disabled-elements)
- img is not listed amount the [elements which have a disabled attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1)

The correct behaviour for non-standard attributes is to add them to the DOM but to otherwise ignore them. Therefore Chrome has the correct behaviour.

---

Images are not interactive controls, so it is generally a bad idea to bind click events to them.

Use a button element instead. You can place an image inside it and style the button so it looks like a plain image. You can disable the button and bind a click event to it.

Comment: Images not being interactive controls seems pretty much a statement of your taste not a fact. What would be the disadvantage of binding a handler to the onclick event of an img element.