# Don't perform action when button is disabled - Ember.js

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I had the following action in my html:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" disabled {{action addVisibilityService target="view"}}>
   element
</a>
```

and I have the function to handle this action:

```
addVisibilityService : function(element){
    console.log("I've been called");
},
```

but the problem is that this action is called when is disabled. So I was wondering how to avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: This wont work. You may need to use a button instead of an anchor. Here more information https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that HTML links cannot be disabled portably (eg [How to disable HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links) also plenty other posts). What you can do is use the `{{if}}` helper and present it as simple text based on a certain state.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sefabibayile/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <i>if value less than 3 characters link disabled</i>
    {{input value=someProp}}
    <br/>
    {{#if somePropOk}}
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" {{action addVisibilityService target="view"}}>
   element
</a>
{{else}}
<span style="font-style:italic;color:grey">element</span>
{{/if}}


  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
   someProp:"test",
  somePropOk:function(){return this.get("someProp").length>3;}.property("someProp")
});
```