# How to disable and re-enable an link with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

can someone explain me how i can disable an link(only disable because i must reenable the link) i have tryed to use this `document.getElementById("aadd").href = "Detail.aspx?using=add";` but when i load the list elements dynamical i cant do it so. because that i ask you how i could disable an link so i cant use it and reenable it?[image]

```
function changebuttonstate(thisbtn) {

        if (document.getElementById("add").disabled == true) {
            document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("aadd").href = "Detail.aspx?using=add";
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("disabledbutton");
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = false;
            }

        } else {
            document.getElementById("add").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("aadd").href = "#";
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("disabledbutton");
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = true;
            }
            thisbtn.disabled = false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("refresh").disabled == true) {
            document.getElementById("refresh").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("arefresh").href = "";
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("disabledbutton");
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = false;
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("refresh").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("arefresh").href = "#";
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("disabledbutton");
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = true;
            }
            thisbtn.disabled = false;

        }
    }

<a href="Detail.aspx?using=edit&id={{x.ID}}"><input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary disabledbutton"/></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger disabledbutton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{x.ID}}" onclick="changebuttonstate(this)">Delete</button>
                <div id="demo{{x.ID}}" class="collapse disabledbutton">
                  <div class="well">
                    <p>Are you sure?</p>
                      <a href="Delete.aspx?id={{x.ID}}"><input type="button" id="Button1" class="btn btn-danger"  value="Delete"/></a>
                  </div>
                </div>

<a href="Detail.aspx?using=add" id="aadd"><input type="button" id="add" value="Add"  class="btn btn-success"/></a>
        <a href="listview.aspx" id="arefresh"><input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh" class="btn btn-primary"/></a>
```

Comment: Side note: I can see you have an `input` within an `a`, which is invalid.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work. I said it is invalid markup. What's the point of having two clickable elements nested? You click one, you clicked both.

Comment: What is wrong with your code is it not working?

Comment: Also, where did you find in the specs that it is valid?

Comment: You are disabling the input correctly but an `<a>` tag doesn't have a disabled property you could prevent the default action of the `<a>` tag

Comment: i have ask ho i could disable the link because when i click on it it works but i need it so that it dont work and after i must reenable it

Comment: @FlorianHofmeister you should probably just get rid of the `<a>` tag altogether and just use the `<input>`

Comment: what bros05 said is correct. you cannot disable a hyperlink by setting disabled=true. read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links. the problem is not about invalid markup.

Comment: MelanciaUK its because the style

Comment: the proplem is that iam using the x.ID and this in couldnt bring to javascript because the get tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable all the links on a page you can use this code:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function stopLinks(e){
    if (this.nodeName==="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

And to re-enable them:

```
document.body.removeEventListener("click", stopLinks);
```

If you only want to disable the links inside a specific element, replace `document.body` with the appropriate element.