# how to disable anchor tag's in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i need to disable the anchor tag below..
am using this coding :(
but it doesn't help me

jquery:-

```
$("a.lookupclick").addClass("viewDisabled");
$(".DeleteRow").addClass("viewDisabled");
$(".viewDisabled").prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$(".lookupclick").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

it works sometimes ,but most of the times it didn't works.. Y? how to prevent to click th

HTML :-

```
<div class="panel1">
  <a tabindex="1" disabled="" class="lookupclick" id="departmentpopup" href="#lookupform" >
     <img class="ImgSearch1" alt="Search" src="/Images/.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links The CSS way is great in the most upvoted answer. jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` can be used when needed. CSS: `.disabled{cursor:not-allowed;}  `.disabled > a{pointer-events:none;}`

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
$("a.lookUpClick").on("click", false);
```

And then:

```
$("a.lookUpClick").off("click");
```

to reactivate them.

Thank you Washington Guedes for the suggested 'golfing'!

Comment: you can just use: _$("a.lookUpClick").on("click", false);_ ... +1 for nice idea... here is a live example: _http://jsfiddle.net/oeppsk4n/_

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a.lookupclick").attr('href','');
```

Comment: That prevents the link from being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can just prevent default function of the link:

```
$('a.lookupclick').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to know the difference between return false and preventDefault take a look at this question - [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways.  You could listen for click events on the link and use the `preventDefault()` method to stop the event.

```
$('a.lookupclick').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Another option is that you can make the `href` attribute of the links `javascript:;` which will cause the links to be clickable but not do anything.  If you need to do this with jQuery you could do it as such:

```
$('a.lookupclick').attr('href','javascript:;');
```