# JQM 1.4.5 : disabling button breaks page rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Going through a steep learning curve, i am currently experimenting various UX 'toys' that i will require to implement an app. One of these is to `disable` a button and `enable` it on the fly. Following the instructions of [**the good book**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable) , I wrote a little snippet of code to test it out. Clicking on "Soap" runs a series of chained promises, and toggles the "Soap1" button `disabled` prop.

**My HTML/JS**

```
<div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" id="btn_soap1" class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back "
       onclick="getInitialNotifications();">Soap1</a>
    <button id="btn_soap" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-icon-bullets "
            onclick="getInitialNotifications();">
        Soap
    </button>

    <script>

        $("#btn_soap1").button({            // required initialization
            disabled:false
        });

        $("#btn_soap").on("click", function () {

            // bubbled from the onClick thingie in the markup

            var isDis = $("#btn_soap1").button("option","disabled");
            $("#btn_soap1").button("option","disabled",!isDis);

//                var but = $("#btn_soap1");
//                var className = "ui-state-disabled";
//                if(but.hasClass(className)) {
//                    but.removeClass(className);
//                } else {
//                    but.addClass(className);
//                }


        });
    </script>
</div>
```

**Intended rendering**

[image]

**Broken rendering** (all browsers and device sims and devices)

[image]

Question : can you see any noob error in the JS that would cause this side-effect. I added (in comments) my work-around, which works as specified, but is seems counter-intuitive.

EDIT: (from Mr. Duc Nguyen's answer). What breaks the rendering is adding the initialization. If it is not there, i get an exception whining that i am calling a function prior to initialization when changing the `disabled` state.

EDIT AGAIN : discovered JSfiddle, ... [a fiddle that reproduces this](http://jsfiddle.net/YvesLeBorg/tb2pLwee/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: new answer basing on jsFiddle

You have gotten yourself in a very interesting situation, some points below:

- jQM has an auto-initaliasation merchanism, if you want to leverage that, you have to follow the rules, or totally disable it and do the initialisation yourself. [jQM global config](https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)
- You have 2 "buttons", but they are actually 1 `<a>` and 1 `<button>`, disabling the `<a>` was never an easy one, have a look here [disabling html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)
- jQM might confuse you that the `<a>` tag is a button widget, but it is not! It just has the same styling as a button, not a button widget. Button widget is only applying to `<button>` and appropriate `<input>` type (it was clearly mentioned in the documents back in 1.2.0's days, I couldn't find it in the 1.4.5 docs)

So, here is how I would do to leverage the jQM auto-initialisation:

```
    <a href="#" id="btn_soap1" class="ui-disabled" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back">Soap1</a>
    <button id="btn_soap" data-inline="true">Soap</button>
```

Notice on the `<a>`:

- The attribute `data-role="button"` was to tell jQM to mark it up as a button
- This class`class="ui-disabled"` was to disable it initially.

And how to disable the link `<a>` on-the-fly. Notice that by just adding a class, it won't work on some specific infamous browsers, referring to the above stackoverflow answer for more information.

```
    var isDis = $("#btn_soap1").hasClass("ui-disabled");
    if (!isDis) {
        $("#btn_soap1").addClass("ui-disabled");
    } else {
        $("#btn_soap1").removeClass("ui-disabled");
    }
```

Again, you can only call `.button([method])` on a real button!

Have a look on this [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb2pLwee/2/), I have cleaned things up a bit.

Comment: That is what i am struggling with. If i do as you suggest, i get an exception `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'` ... suggesting it is not initialized. So i added the 'initialization' stuff, which breaks the rendering.

Comment: Same result (predictably). It is not initialized, thus the initialization code executes ... and breaks rendering. The real issue is `why is it not initialized at that stage in the document's life cycle`. Thanks anyways. +1 for the valiant effort.

Comment: Well, actually, checking for widget initialsed or not is quite tricky with jQM. I've tried the code with 1.4.5 (latest release now) and it worked. I modified the code a little bit to follow http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/

Comment: If you still have issue then the problem must be somewhere else. If you can provide a jsfiddle link, I can help more :)

Comment: thks again for making me discover JSfiddle :) ... if i could i would upvote your answer twice. Fiddle link in the body of the question.

Comment: thanks a million ! lots of good 'up the learning curve' leads in your answer.