# Why Won't Disable Button Work

Tags: javascript

OK, so I have a button that needs to be disabled. I wrote a JavaScript function that is meant to detect if a field is blank/null, and if it is disable the save button next to a field. It would appear to be working as far as detecting the blank field, and throwing the alert, but no matter what I try as far as setting the button to disable. I cannot get it to do so.

Here is what I'm currently trying...

```js
function validateBlank(){
  var x = document.forms["FuForm"]["Field1"].value;
  if (x=null || x == "") {
    alert("Must Be Between 1 and 300 Characters");
    document.getElementById("saveTest").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    return false;
  }
}
```

I've also tried this variant...

```js
document.getElementById("saveTest").disabled
```

and the button/link is setup like this.

```
<a href="#">
 <img id="saveButton" src="${contextPath}/img/icon_sav.gif" name="saveTest" " alt="Disk icon. Save change" title="Save change"/>
</a>
```

Comment: That's not a button, it's an image. You can't disable an image

Comment: It's neither - `saveTest` isn't the `id` of *anything*. `saveButton` is the `id` of an image, though.

Comment: Another typo: `if (x = null) ...` should be `if (x == null) ...`

Comment: What you *want* is to disable the `a` surrounding the `img`. That's [tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
document.getElementById("saveTest").disabled = true;
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: your button is in fact an image, and an image cannot be disabled in this way!
To have an image button that can be disabled, the correct HTML syntax should be in this form:

`<input type="image" src="someimage.png" height="20px" width="20px" id="saveTest"  name="button" />`

i.e. an input of type image .

Comment: Yeah, I tried that earlier, and nothing disabled this button. It's quite bothersome.

Comment: @JackParker That's because it's not a button, and that's not a valid `id` in your HTML. See comments above.

Comment: I did switch the ID back to saveButton. I left saveTest in the earlier code from something I had tried earlier. However, there is code in the website I'm working on that uses a similar function that does disable an image/button, which is why this should work as well.

Comment: I have added a code example of how the HTML syntax should be for an image button that can be disabled in this way :)

Comment: no, the code section where there is an 'input' element of type 'image' , your button must also be an 'input' of  type 'image'