# React not routing to other than "/" route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am not able to render any component on any route other than "/".
Here is my code for routes.js

```
 import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import StockTable from './containers/stockTableContainer';
import StockDetail from './containers/stockDetailContainer';

export const getRoutes = (store) => {
 return(
     <Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path ='/' component ={StockTable}/>
        <Route  path ='/details' component ={StockDetail}/>
    </div>
    </Router>
    )
  }
```

I can render the StockDetail component on "/" route but i can't route it on "/details".

I have also tried using  but still couldn't render "/details"

full code at : https://github.com/shrutis18/stockApp

Comment: Try using `exact` with the other route too, `<Route exact  path ='/details' component ={StockDetail}/>`

Comment: @NileshSingh tried, doesn't work

Comment: You should be using `<Switch>` instead of the `<div>` you have used in your code for routes to change.

Comment: Do you have a Backend that renders your page? If not, you should use a `HashRouter` not a BrowserRouter

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 yes i am making server calls

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 i am using a third party api, and yeah your solution works.But what do you mean by 'do you have a backend that renders your page'.Can you explain why it works for HashRouter but not the regular one

Comment: The BrowserRouter expects your server to render your app on every route. I am actually not sure, since I don't know how the history API works. But I imagine that when you're changing the location of your URI, you send a new request  to that URI, so, if your server doesn't know how to handle that request, your app can't render. A HashRouter only uses the hash portion of your request and doesn't need a server to route since the actual URI is never changing.

Comment: @ShrutiSingh It's just as i thought. I added a reference to the react router FAQ, explaining what happens.

Answer (score 3):

> If your application is hosted on a static file server, you need to use a `<HashRouter>` instead of a `<BrowserRouter>`.

This is because your server doesn't know how to handle requests made to a path other than `/`. For the `BrowserRouter` to work, any routable request should be served the `index.html`.

An excerpt from the [FAQ](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing)

> When you load the root page of a website hosted on a static file
>   server (e.g., http://www.example.com), a `<BrowserHistory>` might appear
>   to work. However, this is only because when the browser makes the
>   request for the root page, the server responds with the root
>   index.html file.
>
> If you load the application through the root page, in-app navigation
>   will work because requests are not actually made to the server. This
>   means that if you load http://www.example.com and click a link to
>   http://www.example.com/other-page/, your application will match and
>   render the /other-page/ route.
>
> However, you will end up with a blank screen if you were to refresh a
>   non-root page (or just attempt to navigate directly to it). Opening up
>   your browser's developer tools, you will see an error message in the
>   console informing you that the page could not be loaded. This is
>   because static file servers rely on the requested file actually
>   existing.

Further along the lines

> This is not an issue when your server can respond to dynamic requests. In that situation, you can instruct the server to catch all requests and serve up the same index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Switch` to your route as directed in the docs

```
<Switch>
   <Route path='some_path' component={Some component} />
</Switch>
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/basic-components.md