# Disable link based on input values: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I noticed that disable is not working as expected for  component in REACT.

```
<Link onClick={() => this.DoSomething()}
disabled={this.props.status != "Approved"}>
<NavDropdown.Item>Approve</NavDropdown.Item>
</Link>
```

I want to stop the traversal of link for particular condition.
--For status =Approved only in this case i want it to call this.DoSomething()

With ternary(conditional) operator condition, i am unable to compare in the LINK component.

I cant not put entire link component in conditional operator as i need NavBar for both the scenarios.

Comment: It may help to share complete component code including the imports, or informing what `Link` is so we can see what props it accepts.

Comment: I think it may be helpful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963070/react-router-how-to-disable-a-link-if-its-active)

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick` will be called whether `disabled` is true or not. If you want to prevent traversal you can do something like this inside `DoSomething`

```
  DoSomething = (e) => {
    if(this.props.status != "Approved") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a variable to use in both in the disabled and the onClick function:

```
const disabled = this.props.status != "Approved"
<Link onClick={() => disabled ? return : this.DoSomething()}
disabled={disabled}>
<NavDropdown.Item>Approve</NavDropdown.Item>
</Link>
```

Disabled is only a boolean, it will never effect your added eventListener onClick.
[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,a%20checkbox%2C%20etc.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,a%20checkbox%2C%20etc.)).