# Disable link <a> inside <li>

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<li>
   <a href="mylink">Some text</a>
</li>
```

I am trying to disable the link via CSS on the parent `<li>` element but to no avail.

```
<li class="disabled">
   <a href="mylink">Some text</a>
</li>
```

And the CSS I have tried:

```
li.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

li.disabled:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
li.disabled a {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

li.disabled a:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: Both work for me in Chrome

Comment: Works in Firefox too. *EDIT:* Doesn't work in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess delirium and insanity setting in. I will go to sleep now and try again tomorrow.

Comment: Putting [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/4808244) here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer), chrome doesn't support `pointer-event`, thus this work around should help you out:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="disabled">
   <a href="http://google.com">Some text</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li.disabled a {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
li.disabled{
  position: relative;
}
li.disabled:before{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsszccmw/2/)