# append link disabled and then enable it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webcam link that I need to place on the page:

```
    $('#chattools').append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="javascript:webcam(\''+to+'\');">webcam</a>');
```

them problem is that I want to add this link disabled, that the user cannot click on it. after a condition I want to enable the click using another JS.

it can be done using jquery or js.

I tried to add disabled on href but nothing happens. any ideas how to do this?

Comment: add `disabled = true`

Comment: use css [pointer events](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) property which can be added through jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTML links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Comment: disabled = true not work, don't know why

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to click it, why do you add the onclick action to it? Just add it after the condition when it should be enabled. And use `.click()` instead of inline JS.

Comment: Disabled is not work for anchor links. its worked for input fields only

Comment: the pointer events did the work well! thank you friends! @PsycoKillers

Answer (score 1):

disabled='disabled' is not working on anchor tags ,
 its supported in old versions only. Please refer below link.

http://techniblogic.com/how-to-disable-anchor-tag-href-links-by-html-css-javascript/#

you can use  below syntax

onclick="return false"

Answer (score 1):

use [css pointer events](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) property which can be added through jQuery!