# ng-disabled on an anchor tag works but tag is still clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an anchor tag that I am using as a download button through boostrap's CSS. My problem is that I have the `ng-disabled` attribute in the tag, and while it makes the button **look** disabled, it can still be clicked. I have something like the following:

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right download-button" target="_self" href="/download" ng-disabled="!dlAvailable">Download</a>
```

The `href="/download"` link varies depending on a few variables, and I need `target="_self"` to make sure the page does not redirect. Is there another way to make the anchor tag look disabled and also not function on a click?

Comment: You can't disable a link, you can change it behavior only: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Comment: Yes! You can not  make it disabled using `ng-disabled`... Use `class` to amke it appear disabled and use `handler` to prevent `default-behavior`

Comment: @AlexanderMac, using CSS `a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}` is something I actually just came across and am trying but it is not currently working. It looks like because it is angularjs disabled, and not html class disabled.

Comment: In Angular the simplest way to do what you need, it's to hide the link and show span with link text. But you can't disable link as button.

Comment: @AlexanderMac my other idea is to duplicate the button and use angular to show/hide the fake buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the 'hack' i used to get around my issue. I duplicated the button and just used `ng-show` to figure out which button should be shown - the disabled one or working one.

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right download-button disabled" target="_self" href="/download" ng-show="!downloadAvailable">download</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right download-button" target="_self" href="/download" ng-show="downloadAvailable">download</a>
```