# Disable all form elements except particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to JQuery.
I need to disable all from elements except with  this class **custom_specialcase**.

Thanks

```
<div>
<button>B1</button><br>
<button class="custom_specialcase">B2</button><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom_specialcase"/>Checkbox1<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Checkbox2<br>
<input type="radio" class="custom_specialcase"/>Radio1<br>
<input type="radio" />Radio2<br>
<select class="custom_specialcase">Select
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
<select >
<option>2</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use selector `"input, select, button"` at call to `jQuery()`, `.not()` with selector `".custom_specialcase"`, `.attr()`, set `disabled` attribute to `"disabled"` at `.ready()` handler

```
$(function() {
  jQuery("input, select, button")
  .not(".custom_specialcase").attr("disabled", "disabled")
})
```

Comment: <div>
<button >B1</button><br>
<table>

<tr>
<td class="custom_specialcase">
<button class="">B2</button><br>
</td></tr></table>

</div>

If this is the case how i can do?

Comment: Include `"td"` or other element that should be excluded at call to `jQuery("input, select, button, table td")`

Comment: not wokring
$(function() {
  jQuery("input, select, button table td")
  .not(".custom_specialcase").attr("disabled", "disabled")
})

Comment: Just noticed. Why do you want to disable a `td` element? Can you describe "not working"?

Comment: <div> <button >B1</button><br> <table> <tr> <td class="custom_specialcase"> <button class="">B2</button><br> </td></tr></table> </div>
in this case this code making both buttons disable .
Sometimes class name will be on td tag not in form element.

Comment: Include descendant selector at `.not()` `.not(".custom_specialcase,.custom_specialcase > *")` https://jsfiddle.net/3fg9gg4x/

Comment: Perfect..Thanks .

Comment: this works for me but how do I include hyperlinks (href) to be disabled too?

Comment: @Jorz You can use `event.preventDefault()` at an attached `click` handler. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links