# Asking user to confirm when deleting an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently deleting a record using the following:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", user_path(user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete %>
```

I was wondering how would I go about using a modal to confirm the deletion?

I want to display a modal (bootstrap), and then have an input box that forces the user to type in the word 'DELETE'.  After hitting submit, it then actually deletes the record.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `confirm` attribute to pop up a browser alert window (the default behavior), you could. . .

Write a javascript action that will open a modal (many examples of this online, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/postpostmodern/1862479) written in coffeescript) with both a text field and a [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/1026898) delete link.

Using javascript, check for changes in the text field using, when the text in the text field reads: `'DELETE'`, use javascript to enable the delete link.

---

Note that this solution will not work if a user is browsing your site with javascript disabled, but neither would many other browser-side confirmation type things.