# How to disable all other links in a div on click of a link in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, disable-link

I am new to Javascript. I wish to disable all other links in a div on click of a link in div.
If I click any link in that div, other links in that div should disable and unclickable.

This code is not making links unclickable on clicking any button . If any link is clicked, the other links in that div should disable and unclickable. For example, If accept link is clicked, the links accept, decline and counter offer links should be unclickable and disable.

Output
[image: Output]

```js
function disableButton() {
  document.querySelector("#notify-div a").removeAttribute("href");

}
```

```html
<div id="notify-div">
  user_name has requested a bid price of bid for quantity of qty for mileage mileage_name of truck truck_name.
  <br> <a href='/truckianAccept/".$lastId."' id='accept' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='disableButton();'>Accept </a>
  <a href='/truckianDecline/".$lastId."' id='decline' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='disableButton();'>Decline </a> <a href='/wstCounterOffer/".$lastId."' id='counter' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='disableButton();'>Counter Offer </a>";
</div>
```

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links) and specifically this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/4218046) to it on how to do this.

Comment: You cannot disable the link AND follow the link unless you use localStorage or something

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the `href`, you set a class with captures the pointer events in css.

```
function disableButtons() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll("#notify-div a");

  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.classList.add('disabled');
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Please note, that `href` and `onClick` won't work together. You should pass a specific function to each link that handles the functionality and disables the buttons afterwards.

Comment: Not working , the button is not disabled, after this code executes

Comment: What is not working? The solution prevents any code from being executed when you click on the link, which is "disabled" by definition. If you want the link to look different, of course you have to change the styling. How to do that is also explained in the already linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links/10276157#10276157). Remember that you can't use `href` and `onclick` together.

Comment: So which function can be used with href?

Comment: None. You use either  the `href` attribute for a url redirect OR `onClick` for executing logical steps. In your case, you need to use `onClick`. In the function that you pass, you first execute the logic connected to the button and afterwards call the function to disable the other buttons.

Comment: <a href='/truckianAccept/".$lastId."' id='accept' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='disableButton();'>Accept </a> . Is it the correct way of calling?

Comment: <a id='accept' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='executeStuffAndDisableButton();'>Accept </a>

Comment: why this function 'executeStuffAndDisableButton();'?

Comment: Because you **cannot** put the href together with `onclick`. Instead you have to do everything inside the function you pass: disabling the buttons as well as the actual logic