# ASP.net Core Conditional disable icon

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Having tried what feels like everything, including the following, I can't find a way of disabling the edit icon based on a condition.

```html
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" disabled="@ViewBag.status">
  <i class="fas fa-edit disabled" style="color:darkolivegreen" title="Edit Bundle" disabled="@ViewBag.status"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you show how you set `ViewBag.status` value?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos  It's set as bool in Controller.  I checked the output in an <h1> tag so it is being set.

Comment: Try adding `a[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }` to your css styles. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped two button options: one enabled and a one disabled in an if(){} and that worked, although not very elegant.  Here is the code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @{
    if (ViewBag.missing == 0)
    {
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled" value="Select Node(s)" />
    }
    else
    {
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Select Node(s)" />
    }
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` doesn't have disable feature. We need to use `pointer-events`. Try code below:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="pointer-events:@(ViewBag.status ? "none":"auto" )">
    <i class="fas fa-edit disabled" style="color:darkolivegreen;" title="Edit Bundle" >jump</i>
</a>
```