# Intercepting ill formated link clicks with QWebEngineView in PyQt6

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt6, qt6

I would like to intercept any click on a link, including a baddly formated one, in a PyQt6 WebEngineView.

For example, in the following code snippet the page becomes blank if I click the link "test". I would like a way to make it do nothing except call a custom function (say print the link, for example).

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml("<a href=\"test_bad_link\">test</a>")
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

So I am looking for a way to have the code print "test_bad_link" whenever I click on "test" in the WebView.

I already tried multiple variations of modifying the "acceptNavigationRequest" of the underlying QWebEnginePage or setting a "QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor" and defining my desired behavior in the "interceptRequest" function.

These approaches work well for valid URL, but not if the link is an arbitrary string, like in my example. Instead, neither function is ever called and the page just goes blank.

---

The following code snippet shows a synthesis of my previous attempts:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo, QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor, QWebEngineProfile

import sys


class Intercept(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
        def interceptRequest(self, info: QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo) -> None:
                print("Interceptor trigger")

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
        def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, type, isMainFrame: bool) -> bool:
                print("Page overwrite trigger")
                if type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationType.NavigationTypeLinkClicked: return False
                return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url, type, isMainFrame)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
profile = QWebEngineProfile()
interceptor = Intercept()
profile.setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
page = Page(profile)
rf = QWebEngineView(page)
rf.setHtml("<a href=\"test\">test baddly formated</a> <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">test well formated</a> ")
rf.show()
app.exec()
app.quit()
```

The window this produces contains two links, "test baddly formated" and "test well formated".
Clicking "test baddly formated" prints neither "Page overwrite trigger" nor  "Interceptor trigger" and instead leads to a blank page.
Clicking "test well formated" prints "Page overwrite trigger" but not "Interceptor trigger" and the page does not change.

I was hoping for this code to trigger a print in the first case. The second is in line with my expectations and I think I understand it.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre] that includes the QWebEnginePage implementations of the above attempts.

Comment: Done, though I am interested in any way to get the behavior I described, even if it has nothing to do with my own attempts.

Comment: As [stated in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest), you must specify a base url when using `setHtml`, otherwise relative links cannot be intercepted. As a bare minimum, e.g. `QtCore.QUrl('file:')` will suffice for the purposes of testing - but obviously if you expect relative urls to actually work, you will have to supply a more appropriate value. (PS: you should also take heed of the other two notes in the above link, esp. the one regarding fragment links).

Comment: You can't do that with the ```QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()``` or ```acceptNavigationRequest()```, because the browser engine does not request anything for an invalid URL as the names imply. It's an XY problem. Why not inject Javascript code for doing that?

Comment: I included a description of what I tried because musicamante asked me to but I did not expect there to be a way to "fix" it and make it work. I was a bit worried that including that code would lead to people focusing on it. This is not a debug question, but rather a "How can I" question.

I do not know how to get the behavior I want through javascript injection, but if you can show me I would be grateful.  @relent95

Comment: It seems that if I set a default URL "http://defaulturl" as I call setHtml then some bad links are taken as relative links and I get "http://defaulturl/test". Makes sense.
However some bad links (for example with meaningless protocoles like "testHello:test") are interpreted as normal links.  Also, I cannot just set an empty base URL, which would have been perfect (same behavior as not giving a base URL).
Using the relative link behavior to handle bad links seems error prone. For example, it will fail if the bad link is just "#".

Comment: See the [```runJavaScript()```](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/1186624).

Comment: "runJavascript" seem to be the wrong function for this as it just runs some javascript once, rather than tying it to an event. I know very little about javascript, so maybe there is an obvious way to make it work that I am missing.
Also I assume you are refering to the "Fake click handler" or maybe "Intercept clicks" methods of the answer you provided? In both cases I have no idea how to make it work through "runJavascript" in that context.
Could you kindly provide some code to show how this would work?

Comment: @RealPlants For me, using a base-url does exactly what you asked for, which is to "intercept any click on a link". I don't know what you mean by some urls being "interpreted as normal links". In all cases, `acceptNavigationRequest` is predictably invoked, which allows the url to be handled as appropriate. As I pointed out above, the behaviour with `#fragment` links is documented. If you want notifcations for those as well, you can use [QWebEngineScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginescript.html) and [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebchannel.html) to bind javascript handlers.

Comment: @RealPlants, Ekhumoro is right. I was wrong. You can use the ```QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()``` or ```acceptNavigationRequest()``` for filtering an invalid URL. Specify a base URL when calling the ```setHtml()```.

Comment: @RealPlants PS: the behaviour of relative links is not "error prone". The links are resolved in accordance with the standard internet RFC for Relative Uniform Resource Locators. Thus: `base = QUrl('http://defaulturl/'); base.resolved(QUrl('test'))` -> `QUrl('http://defaulturl/test')` and `base.resolved(QUrl('test:foo'))` -> `QUrl('test:foo')`. This is exactly same behaviour as e.g. [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin).

Comment: I understand the resolving process for links and acceptNavigationRequest follow their standards and documentations. When I say "error prone", it is more a comment on my ignorance: "I don't know the rules about what can break normal link handling so I think if I try to play around it I will create errors". I also understand that links starting with a # are seen as anchors and not passed to acceptNavigationRequest. To me this means that overloading that function is not the right way to get the behavior I want. 
Anyway, I did manage to make it work with Javascript and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by injecting javascript.
I add some javascript as a suffix to the html. Said javascript blocks the default behavior of all link clicks and outputs the link href value to the console. It also adds a prefix to distinguish these messages from other javascript console messages.
By overloading the javaScriptConsoleMessage function of QWebEnginePage I take this message, check the prefix to make sure this is not another javascript message, and then feed the rest of the message to a given function. In this example, it prints the message.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage

def myfunction(linktext):
    print(linktext)

class CustomWebPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        if message[:15] == "outputting link": myfunction(message[15:])

class CustomWebView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPage(CustomWebPage(self))

    def setHtml(self, html: str | None) -> None:
        suffix = """
        <script>
            document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
                link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log("outputting link" + link.getAttribute('href'));
                });
            });
        </script>
        """ 
        html = html + suffix
        return super().setHtml(html)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.browser = CustomWebView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    html = """ <a href=\"test\">print test</a> <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">print example domain</a> <a href=\"#\">print #</a> """
    window.browser.setHtml(html)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If the html code in question already contains a <script> element it might be better to put the additional javascript inside it.

Comment: In order to be fully candid, I have to say that I got the signature of the function javaScriptConsoleMessage and the core elements of the javascript code by asking chatGPT. I wrote almost all of the python code myself and I understand it all. I decided this was enough of a grey area regarding the rules on AI generated answers to make it ok to post the answer. This is only because I have now fully solved the problems insofar as I needed to and I thought my solution might be useful to others in the future.