# Best way to disable button in Twitter's Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap

I am confused when it comes to disabling a `<button>`, `<input>` or an `<a>` element with classes: `.btn` or `.btn-primary`, with JavaScript/jQuery.

I have used a following snippet to do that:

```
$('button').addClass('btn-disabled');
$('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

So, if I just provide the `$('button').addClass('btn-disabled');` to my element, it will appear as disabled, visually, but the functionality will remain the same and it will be clickable nontheless, so that it the reason why I added the `attr` and `prop` settings to the element.

Has anyone expirenced this same issue out there? Is this the right way of doing this - while using Twitter's Bootstrap?

Comment: Could check for hasclass on any attached events, but with an href I'm not sure

Comment: @ZachLeighton - when it comes to "a", you have to provide an event handler for click action

Comment: I don't think you can disable a link.

Comment: I've found that you can in fact disable a link if you bind to a click event on it and call event.preventDefault().  But I wouldn't be surprised if that doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: This was not a duplicate. The duplicate referenced does not cover the case for an "a" href element with classes: "btn" or "btn btn-primary" as stated in the question.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You just need the `$('button').prop('disabled', true);` part, the button will automatically take the disabled class.

Comment: Does not work for anchors, see my answer

Comment: To also stop the click event firing, add a class with `pointer-events: none` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19477318/45525

Comment: Add this style to your css `a[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: I have just tried this with Bootstrap 3 and `$('.button').prop('disabled', true);` stops click event propagation, i.e. Bootstrap takes care of that for you.

Comment: Does not work for `<button class="close">` e.g. close button in a modal. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: This does not work in my case.

Comment: Also don't forget to add the aria-disabled='true' attribute, as per recommendation.

Answer (score 124):

For input and button:

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

For anchor:

```
$('a').attr('disabled', true);
```

Checked in firefox, chrome.

See http://jsfiddle.net/czL54/2/

Comment: When you add a click handler to disabled anchor link, it should not work. But in your provided example, click handler is also fired. http://jsfiddle.net/76wmpohs/

Comment: This seems to be sufficient for Bootstrap 3.  It appears bootstrap is doing something on setting a btn to be visually disabled that also is preventing the click event from firing.  In pure jQuery and HTML without Bootstrap 3, such as some of the fiddle examples, it appears to be a more complicated story.  But this question was in context of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 90):

Building off [jeroenk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335798/165673), here's the rundown:

```
$('button').addClass('disabled'); // Disables visually
$('button').prop('disabled', true); // Disables visually + functionally

$('input[type=button]').addClass('disabled'); // Disables visually
$('input[type=button]').prop('disabled', true); // Disables visually + functionally

$('a').addClass('disabled'); // Disables visually
$('a').prop('disabled', true); // Does nothing
$('a').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disables visually
```

See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/czL54/13/)

Comment: nice comprehensible example!

$('#button-2').attr('disabled', 'disabled')  

Worked for both buttons as well as links.

Comment: @msanjay: No - the fiddle uses Bootstrap 2 and *visually* disables links/anchors, but doesn't *functionally* disable them, like the comment says. If you change it to BS3 it also functionally disables them.

Comment: EML makes an important point.  That in Boot Strap 3, setting the disabled attribute is suffiicent, and Bootrap 3 will handle the rest for you.  But in jQuery and HTML (without Bootstrap 3), then such is not sufficient.

Answer (score 38):

The easiest way to do this, is to use the `disabled` attribute, as you had done in your original question:

`<button class="btn btn-disabled" disabled>Content of Button</button>`

As of now, Twitter Bootstrap doesn't have a method to disable a button's functionality without using the `disabled` attribute.

Nonetheless, this would be an excellent feature for them to implement into their javascript library.

Comment: which is what the OP's snippet is doing

Comment: @Eonasdan Correct, as that was the best way to achieve his desired result. I was simply restating what he had done was correct.

Comment: (Sorry if you see a downvote notification, I clicked on the wrong thing)

Answer (score 31):

```
<div class="bs-example">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="button">Active</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success disabled" type="button">Disabled</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Real solution for the question. No JQuery needed.

Comment: This is actually the correct solution for bootstrap buttons.

Comment: doesnt work for chrome

Comment: Works in Chrome, and is the recommended method to set a button non-clickable when using Bootstrap.

Comment: This doesn't prevent click events from firing.

Comment: Set disabled="disabled" to prevent click events from firing.

Answer (score -1):

What ever attribute is added to the button/anchor/link to disable it, bootstrap is just adding style to it and user will still be able to click it while there is still onclick event. So my simple solution is to check if it is disabled and remove/add onclick event:

```
if (!('#button').hasAttr('disabled'))
 $('#button').attr('onclick', 'someFunction();');
else
 $('#button').removeattr('onclick');
```

Comment: You probably meant `removeAttr` instead of `removeattr`.

Comment: Yes, .removeAttr() is the method name [link](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

Comment: That probably will not remove an onclick event, attached with on() calls.