# Disable and Enable Click event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please advise how to disable /enable the click function using jquery api. Based on the role i have show the sports page to the user.

Using below bootstrap code for UI.

```
<div id="viewtest" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button id="C" class="btn btn-default" title="Cricket">Cricket</button>
    <button id="B" class="btn btn-default" autofocus="autofocus" autofocus title="BaseBall">BaseBall</button>
    <button id="T" class="btn btn-default disabled" title="Tennis">Tennis</button>
    <button id="G" class="btn btn-default disabled " title="Monthly">Golf</button>
</div>
```

I am using below function to handle the above buttons click events.

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary").siblings().removeClass("btn-primary");
    viewtype = this.id;
    $(this).blur();
    showPage();
});
```

For some criteria , i am disabling the click event using below function

```
var disableOptionsTabs=["C","T"];
        disableButtons(disableOptionsTabs);

function disableButtons(mybuttons) {
    $.each(mybuttons, function (key, value) {
        $("#" + value).off();
    });
}
```

Please advise how to enable the click event? or how to bind the click function for button.

I am using below method ,bind the click event for the specify buttons based on given advise . but it's not working.

```
 var enableOptionsTabs=["C","T"];
            enableButtons(enableOptionsTabs);
    function enableButtons(mybuttons){
           $.each( mybuttons, function( key,value ) 
           { $( "#" + value ).on("click",myOnClick);  }
          );

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to continually remove and add the event I would move the click functionality to a function you can reuse.

```
function myOnClick () {
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary").siblings().removeClass("btn-primary");
    viewtype = this.id;
    $(this).blur();
    showPage();
}
```

Then you can attach it like so:

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").on('click', myOnClick);
```

And remove it like so:

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").off('click');
```

As for the disabling loop if `mybuttons` is a list of elements you can just do this:

```
function disableButtons(mybuttons) {
    $.each(mybuttons, function () {
        $(this).off('click');
    });
}
```

You can because of how jQuery calls the function you pass it to `each`. It sets the context of that function for every element so you can just reference it using `this`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can we do without function ?

Comment: Sure you can continually use an anonymous function if you want.

Comment: Do we need pass the current object ie this()  to myOnclick function ?

Comment: `this` is the context of the function, you don't need to pass it. It's just there and in your case references the element that was clicked.

Comment: Using your suggestion ,we can disable the click event for the all button and vice versa,but my requirement is  enable/disable the event based on the conditions, so that i am using off method in the loop.

Comment: The given below code used to disable the click event for Cricket/Tennis .var disableOptionsTabs=["C","T"]; disableButtons(disableOptionsTabs);

Comment: Yes, I gave you an example on how to disable the 'click' event. Then I also showed you how to properly use your disableButtons method to disable buttons that are in the list you pass it. Did you read the entire answer?

Comment: Ah see there is some code you didn't include. As I said in my answer if that list was actual DOM elements loop using this. Since those are just strings which I assume are referencing IDs than go back to your old loop using $('#' + value).off('click')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95959/discussion-between-vasanth-dha-and-atheistp3ace).

Comment: Stil i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from the below link ,

[Best way to disable button in Twitter's Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327668/best-way-to-disable-button-in-twitters-bootstrap)

```
function disableButtons(mybuttons){
             $.each( mybuttons, function( key,value ) 
      {         $("#" + value).prop('disabled', true)     }
      );

    }
    function enableButtons(mybuttons){
       $.each( mybuttons, function( key,value ) 
       { 

       $("#" + value).prop('disabled', false);
       $("#" + value).removeClass("disabled");

       }
      );

    }
```