# Javascript to disable the click

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="one">this should be disabled button</a>
<a href="#" onclick='$("a#one").click();'>click button 2</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').click({
        alert("clicked!");
    });
});
```

How do I make the 1st link unclickable, while the 2nd link actually clicks the 1st link.

Answer (score 3):

Simply trigger the click after disabling what you want disabled:

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/dd5ppr93/).

**CSS**

```
.disableClick {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="one" class="disableClick">this should be disabled button</a><br />
<a href="#" id="two">click button 2</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one').click(function () {
    alert("Link one clicked!");
  });

  $("#two").click(function () {
    $("#one").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

**Additional Information**

As it relates to disabling your anchor, there are lots of options. Start here - [How do you make an anchor link non-clickable or disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654900/how-do-you-make-an-anchor-link-non-clickable-or-disabled)

Comment: What are you writing? Where do I put this, its not working

Comment: I want to click the 1st link via javascript but not directly when the 1st link is clicked.

Comment: @Prakash, did you downvote because you didn't understand my answer? That's demotivation for you...

Comment: @Prakash, I've added a working fiddle to demonstrate. FYI - It's generally considered distasteful to be short/rude with people trying to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use [jquery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), where you will bind the event everytime and use it

```
<a href="#" id="one">this should be disabled button</a>
<a href="#" id="two">click button 2</a>
```

Observe that I have added an id to the second anchor tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').unbind("click"); //unbind the click on the first anchor
    $('#two').bind("click", function(){ //bind it for once.

        $('#one').one("click", function(){
           alert( "one click triggered" );
        });         
        $( "#one" ).trigger( "click" ); //trigger the click after binding it for one
    });

});
```