# How to use the disabled attribute for a <a> tag in HTML

Tags: css, html

How to use the `disabled` attribute for a  tag in HTML

I have tried this

```
<a href="#" disabled>
    My Link
</a>
```

Comment: <a href="/home" disabled>My Link</a>

Comment: Clearly an duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654900/how-do-you-make-an-anchor-link-non-clickable-or-disabled#], [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links/10276157#10276157]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `disabled` attribute for `<a>` tag. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 37):

```css
a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="disabled">Click me</a>
```

Please check the above code. It may help you out.

Answer (score 10):

There is no disabled attribute like this`(<a href="#" disabled>)` for "a" tag. you can try disabling using css so just add class in your "a" tag & then disable using css.

```
<a href="#" class="disable">
    My Link
</a>
.disable {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:-

```
<style>
.disabled{
    /*Disabled link style*/
    color:black;
}
</style>

<a class="disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a>
```